# LibreImpress deleting inserted pdf images after a while

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I have Libre Office 5.4.6.2 40m0(Build:2) on Ubuntu 17.10

My LibreOffice Impress keeps deleting all the `.pdf` images I insert to it every so often (can't figure out the periodicity yet). It looks like [this](https://scontent.fscl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/31886551_2029692340690917_2867712735410388992_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=33c04811b738dcc25f221c576fe23fa8&oe=5B9A7505) when it happens... it only happens to the `.pdf` files, all the `.png` that were inserted are fine. Besides happening every so often out of nowhere, it also happens when I try to export to a `pdf` with the images looking fine before and not afterwards (and also not visible in the pdf) and when I close the file.

I have increased the memory by a lot, and have gotten rid of the autosaving feature some other questions blamed. My memory is now as [this](https://scontent.fscl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/31870480_2029693440690807_1380355124035059712_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=053058a469631397f517f6306e84eca3&oe=5B5EC945).

Neither of those two solutions have fixed my problem.
I would apprecciate a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It is hugely unlikely anyone can help you here, but if you'd submit a bug report directly to LibreOffice they might get to fixing it eventually. In the mean time you might want to look into Latex and TexStudio for document management - that combination is WAY more powerful and stable.

Comment: Thanks! I also think it's unlikely that someone will be able to help me here, but I dont lose anything in trying. I have used beamer in the past but I can never make it look how I want it to look, which is why I have been using Libre Impress. I will see if now I can find templates to my liking.